# how can i overcome this compilation error?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, compiler-errors, hive

Actually i am new to eclipse and jdbc connections i tried to connect to hive database on my centos and am trying to perform queries on a table in hive database through the following code.And am facing compilation problem for this code.plz help me..

```
<%@page import="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.math.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.Map.Entry"%>
<%

try {
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").newInstance();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
System.out.println("error:unable to load driver class");
System.exit(1);
}

%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>server side</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/nikhildb");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String country_name = request.getParameter("country_name");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * from population where    country_name ='"+country_name+"'");
if(!rs.next()){
    System.out.println("Sorry, no country exists");
}
else{
%>
```

i had some table details in html after else statement.

[this is the photo copy of compilation error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H7FK.png)
plzz help me..!

Answer (score 0):

Your HiveDriver is a packages - "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver resolves to a package", so the correct way to import it is:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.*"%>
```

I can't say, where and how many time you have to fix it, though.

Comment: Actually this is my import statement                                                    <%@page import="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"%>                                      am unable extent after HiveDriver.* can u suggest me the required jar file for this

Comment: maybe this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhive041jar.htm). I'm not entirely sure what u need.

Comment: same compilation problem continues even after adding that jar file.plzz help me

Comment: Previous answer has not helped me.Can u plzz help me Mr.ArchLicher ...thanks for your previous answer.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I have